# Runtime.getRuntime().exec() don`t work when there is a space in File-Url?

Tags: java, runtime.exec

I´am facing a very strange Problem right now. It took me 2 hours to reproduce and get the "solution" of this error.

This happens:

I try to start another .jar file, located in `System.getProperty("user.dir")` .

actually, I use this for start:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java -jar "+System.getProperty("user.dir")+System.getProperty("file.separator")+"myJar.jar");
```

This works fine if the `System.getProperty("user.dir")` 's will look like this for example:

`C:\MyProgramm\`

But if the `System.getProperty("user.dir")` look like:

`C:\My Programm\`

it will not work. It´s strange, beacuase there is no exception thrown.
Please, if you can, and if my Explanation is clear enough, can you give me a solution for this issue?

Sorry for my english, please do not hesitate to ask all questions if something is unlear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use quotes around a path if it contains spaces.

```
java -jar "C:\My path has spaces\my app.jar"
```

In your specific case:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java -jar \""+System.getProperty("user.dir")+System.getProperty("file.separator")+"myJar.jar\"");
```

Where `\"` is the escape character for `"`.

[Read more here about escape characters](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html)

Comment: I do not hard-code the path, I did it this way: `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java -jar "+System.getProperty("user.dir")+System.getProperty("file.separator")+"myJar.jar");`

Comment: @ÂlexBay Read the answer, I updated it in the exact moment you wrote your comment :)

Comment: :) seems to work like a charm, I will do some checks and mark this answer as right if I don´t face a Problem. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

> if my Explanation is clear enough, can you give me a solution for this issue?

When you give a single string for it to run it expects to use space as a seperator e.g.

```
java -jar C:\My Program\myJar.jar
```

has four words

```
java
-jar
C:\My
Program\myJar.jar
```

The simple solution is to not get it to do the parsing.

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] {
    "java", "-jar", System.getProperty("user.dir")+System.getProperty("file.separator")+"myJar.jar" } );
```

Now it no longer sees space as a separator.

When you run a program, errors are sent to the error stream, and do not trigger an exception. I suggest you always read the error stream to see what errors you might be getting.

Comment: Compiler said "no suitable method found for exec(String,String,String)

Comment: In that case try `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] { "java", "-jar", System.getProperty("user.dir")+System.getProperty("file.separator")+"myJar.jar" } );`

Comment: @ÂlexBay Which version of Java do you have?

Comment: I use  JDK 1.7.0_55, I will give it a try! edit: Yes, this methods works also very good. Thank you very much! upvoted

Answer (score 2):

You shall put your commands in a `String[]` like this:

```
String[] command = new String[]{"java","-jar",System.getProperty("user.dir")+System.getProperty("file.separator")+"myJar.jar"};
```

and than use

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
```

Hope this helps.